# Centralized local hosted web based password manager

Tags: encryption, web-application, password-management

In our company we have more than 100 employers and everyone use several online applications daily. To access all of this sites they need a password which was now stored very insecurely. so I'm planning to deploy a centralized password manager that can access via web browser within our local area network.

I read little bit then I found that locally deployable web based *opensource* passwords managers are very rare. I found one that called RatticDB but unfortunately it store all passwords in plain text. they suggest encrypt the data volume which I don't like.

Could someone give me a possible and alternative to the [ratticDB](http://rattic.org/) with encryption. or my appdev guy said that he can develop one with encryption but i worried about quality. Should I go with him ?

Comment: By "local" do you mean "local to the user's PC" (e.g. localhost) or just local to your company (e.g. only accessible internally on the LAN)?

Comment: Yes I only want to use it inside the LAN.

Comment: Should we assume you only care about free/open source solutions?  There are several commercial solutions but that's not the vibe I'm getting from your question.

Comment: currently I'm looking for opensource solution. But I would thankful if you can name some commercial solutions since opensource solutions are very rare. I already look lastpass and dashlane they both don't offer local password storage. Actually I don't like cloud ;)

Comment: Check out http://keepass.info/. It is not web-based, but you can have a db-file per employee stored centrally on your LAN. I think its better than web-based because no XSS will be able to steal from a separate application.

Comment: https://github.com/sukria/WebKeePass and https://bitbucket.org/namn/browsepass/ tho I can't recommend as I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a list of tools I evaluated so far (July 2016).

**sysPass**

[sysPass](https://github.com/nuxsmin/sysPass) is a PHP web based Password Manager for business and personal use.

- AES-256 encryption in CBC mode
- RSA for sending passwords from forms
- Two factor authentication
- HTML5 and Ajax interface
- Users, groups and profiles management (up to 20 access levels)
- MySQL, OpenLDAP and Active Directory authentication
- Custom fields
- Activity notices by email and event log
- Accounts history
- Multilanguage
- API

**Vaultier**

Safely store and share passwords or even files with people you work with!
There is a free community edition and a hosts Saas solution.

https://www.vaultier.org/

**Teampass**

[Teampass](https://github.com/nilsteampassnet/TeamPass) is a Collaborative Passwords Manager

**Passbolt**

[Passbolt](https://github.com/passbolt/passbolt) is an open source password manager for teams. It allows to securely share and store credentials. For instance, the wifi password of your office, or the administrator password of a router, or your organisation social media account password, all of them can be secured using Passbolt.

Passbolt is different from the other password managers because:

- It is free & open source
- It is respectful of privacy
- It is primarily designed for teams and not individuals
- It is based on OpenGPG, a proven cryptographic standard
- It is easy to use for both novice and IT professionals alike
- It is extensible thanks to its restful API
- Has Chrome and Firefox extensions

**Team Password Manager**

Is PHP based Password management software for groups.

- Fine-grained group policies
- Multiple Projects and Subproject password groups.
- LDAP/AD Integration

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for sounds like Privileged Access Management - a central database that stores administrative and other non-user credentials and allows authorized users to "check them out" for use.  Such systems often will programmatically change the credentials on the target system so as to prevent re-use outside the window for which access was granted.

The most prominent example of this sort of software is [CyberArk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyberArk).  You install it on your network, tell it how to authenticate your users, then you start stuffing credentials into it and, if possible, telling it how to "manage" credentials.  It can be configured to change them regularly (e.g. every 60 days), after use, or however you like.

Competitors to CyberArk include [Dell Privileged Password Manager](http://software.dell.com/products/privileged-password-manager/) and [BeyondTrust PowerBroker](http://www.beyondtrust.com/Products/PrivilegedAccountManagement/).  And [here's a wider list of products that "compete" with CyberArk](https://www.scmagazineuk.com/privileged-access-management/grouptest/743/), ranging from local single-user to cloud multi-user, you might find a match for your needs somewhere on this list.

It is possible that [OpenIAM Access Manager](https://www.openiam.com/products/access-manager/overview/), which is Open Source, would provide the functionality you're looking for - but OpenIAM addresses a much wider swath of the Identity Management field, so I'm not sure if it would be suitable for what seems like a more limited need on your part.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sounds like this is good way to secure credentials but what i'm looking for is more smaller scale application than this. My main concern is store password securely in centralized database and provide web interface for user to access them with password. and that application don't need to compatible with any other commercial solutions and don't need advanced featured found on privileged management systems. that's why I looking for cost effective or completely opensource system

Comment: The link of *"wider list of products that "compete" with CyberAr"* seems broken in a way - it currently lists *FileZilla*, *Adobe Reader Mobile*, *PuTTY*, and *AngularJs* as alternatives. It goes on with similarly unrelated software.

Comment: @Kobi looks like that list rotted over time, I've replaced it with a more accurate equivalent link.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into [Vault](https://vaultproject.io/). Vault is an open source tool that provides centralized secret storage that can be accessed over a REST API. It has various methods of authentication (like auth tokens or certificates) and provides policies that can be used for authorization.

Keep in mind that it is a good idea to take a step back and look at your overarching pattern here. In your post you mentioned "To access all of this sites they need a password which was now stored very insecurely", which seems to imply that they are using a shared password. This is insecure in-and-of itself; if you have a shared password, storing it securely won't make it much more secure. Every person who uses it could be a point of failure. If you're talking instead about people using their own passwords to access various external services, it might make more sense for them to use something like [lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) locally. Otherwise if you're having people access your tools, then having a good SSH key structure would be much more secure than having a shared password (where users generate a keypair and send you their public key, and use their private key for authentication to services).

Vault is a good tool, but make sure that you question your assumptions here about what information you want to store in a centralized secret management system, and if that is the best way to do it.